# Android Java: Why does adding weeks worth of miliseconds to a date, makes it go back in time?

Tags: java, android, datetime, calendar

I have this date and I want to forward it ahead in time, adding a few weeks to it.

This is how I do it

```
    int weeks = 4;

newDate.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hoursAndMinutes.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
newDate.set(Calendar.MINUTE, hoursAndMinutes.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
newDate.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
newDate.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, Utils.returnRandomNumberBetween(1, 999));
dateFormat.format(newDate.getTime());

dateInMiliseconds = newDate.getTimeInMillis() + weeks * 604800000; // 604800000 is a week's worth of miliseconds
```

Now, instead of moving the date like 4 weeks ahead, it moves it back to the same week day but in May?

**EDIT: To the guys that pointed out my question is a possible duplicate - it would have been a possible duplicate if I knew the problem was in casting, which I didnt know.**

Comment: Is the product higher than 2^31?

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `java.util.Calendar`, and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now legacy, supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & Java 7 in the [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. Further adapted for earlier Android in the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Integer overflow. `weeks * 604800000` is computed as 32-bit signed int and it overflows. Specifically, its bit #31 (the sign bit) is set, making it negative.

Promote either operand to long to compute as 64-bit signed long integers, e.g.

```
dateInMiliseconds = newDate.getTimeInMillis() + weeks * 604800000L;
```

Answer (score 1):

Integer overflow from weeks * 604,800,000

Max integer value is ~2,147,000,000
you multiply 4 with 604,800,000 ~= 2,400,000,000